# I cannot build an ASP.NET MVC Core 6 app, using Telerik's AutoComplete; cannot find package

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, nuget

We're working on a new ASP.NET MVC Core app, using .NET 6 and VS 2022. We're also trying to use Telerik (Progress) Kendo UI for jQuery. I've been corresponding with Telerik's tech support, but with very little to show for it. They've provided me with a sample app, which I cannot build on my machine. I've installed Kendo UI for jQuery on my dev box. Whenever I try to build the sample app I get this error:

> NU1102    Unable to find package Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core with version (>= 2022.1.412)

Following the instructions to add Telerik's NuGet package to my dev box [which I found here](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/installation/nuget-install) and supplying my credentials for my Telerik account. However, that doesn't make a difference. I still get the error I've provided. The error above has 3 sublines, which are as follows:

- Found 1 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 2016.3.914 ]
- Found 0 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
- Found 0 version(s) in Telerik NuGet Feed TelerikAspNetCoreApp512

So, even though I've added Telerik's NuGet server, added my credentials (which I verify work by going to the URL in a browser), got out of VS 2022, then back in again, I still cannot build the app.

I've looked up Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core errors here on SO. I've found only 3 posts. One for deploying the app, another using Azure Pipelines and the third using Jenkins builds. But none of the address the issue I'm having.

I believe I've got VS 2022 configured correctly, Telerik's NuGet server is available, etc. Nothing obvious appears to me as to what is preventing me from building the app on my dev box.

Comment: So you're wanting to use both `UI for jQuery` and `UI for Asp.Net Core`?

Comment: No. We want to use `UI for jQuery`. The `UI for ASP.NET` comes from a sample project I got from Telerik. That is, I've tried to add `UI for jQuery` to the sample project. Was that wrong?

Comment: Can you send to Tech Support the repo of the demo app you are working on, or credentials for your failing environment? Not all tech support departments are willing to sign into someone else's machine, but it may be worth a try - I don't think there is enough information in your post for readers to replicate what you are seeing.

Comment: If you don't want to use the HTML or Tag Helpers, then you don't need the NuGet package. If using only Kendo UI get the scripts and styles as shown [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/hosting-kendoui) and you should be ready to go.